# Electromagnetic Wave In Toroidal and Helical Waveguide

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, waveguide

Is there an analytic solution for the propagation (modes) of electromagnetic wave in a toroidal and helical waveguide? References would be appreciated too.

Comment: see Karbowiak "MICROWAVE ASPECTS OF WAVEGUIDES FOR LONG-DISTANCE TRANSMISSION" and Fowler "Analysis of Helical Transmission Lines by Means of the Complete Circuit Equations", and the references to and from, etc. This is a massive subject and was analyzed for  at least in three contexts (1) TWAs, (2) low-loss transmission, (3) helcial antennas.

Comment: @hyportnex: Thank you so much! Unfortunately both references you provided are behind a pay wall. Do you have any other references, just as complete, that are more easily accessible? Text books qualify as well.

Comment: http://www.jpier.org/PIERB/pierb16/07.09022202.pdf

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.00496.pdf

Comment: and 3 classics from Unger: https://archive.org/details/bstj40-1-255 ; https://archive.org/details/bstj40-2-613 ; https://archive.org/details/bstj37-6-1599